# After loading a pretrained Word2Vec model, how do I get word2vec representations of new sentences?

Tags: cluster-analysis, gensim, word2vec

I loaded a word2vec model using Google News dataset. Now I want to get the Word2Vec representations of a list of sentences that I wish to cluster. After going through the [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) I found this `gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence`but I'm not sure this is what I am looking for.

There should be a way to get word2vec representations of a list of sentences from a pretrained model right? None of the links I searched had anything about it. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: word2vec maps *words* to vectors, not sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word2Vec only offers vector representations for words, not sentences.

One crude but somewhat effective (for some purposes) way to go from word-vectors to vectors for longer texts (like sentences) is to average all the word-vectors together. This isn't a function of the gensim `Word2Vec` class; you have to code this yourself.

For example, with the word-vectors already loaded as `word_model`, you'd roughly do:

```
import numpy as np

sentence_tokens = "I do not like green eggs and ham".split()
sum_vector = np.zeros(word_model.vector_size)
for token in sentence_tokens:
    sum_vector += word_model[token]
sentence_vector = sum_vector / len(sentence_tokens)
```

Real code might add handling for when the tokens aren't all known to the model, or other ways of tokenizing/filtering the text, and so forth.

There are other more sophisticated ways to get the vector for a length-of-text, such as the 'Paragraph Vectors' algorithm implemented by gensim's `Doc2Vec` class. These don't necessarily start with pretrained word-vectors, but can be trained on your own corpus of texts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried out Doc2Vec but my corpus is too small for me to effectively train the model. That's the reason I was trying to implement a pre-trained Word2Vec model.